# Where is the reverse proxy config in artifactory-registry docker image

Tags: nginx, docker, artifactory

I am trying out the docker-registry docker image version 4.7.0 to test out the docker repositories in artifactory. I mounted the following volumes

-v $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data
-v $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs 
-v $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/backup 
-v $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc

Is there a way I can look at the nginx configuration for the repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nginx configuration files should be under the Nginx directory at  /etc/nginx/ inside the docker container.